# Form can't scroll when contains list lwuit

Tags: list, scroll, lwuit

Here's my code:

```
public Form getMenuForm()
{
    if ( menuForm == null )
    {
        Form menuForm = new Form( "Tracking Main Menu" );
        menuForm.setLayout( new BoxLayout( BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );
        menuForm.setScrollable( true );
        menuForm.setScrollableY( true );
        menuForm.addComponent( this.getMenuList() );
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            Label lblTest = new Label("hello guys");
            menuForm.addComponent( lblTest );
        }
        menuForm.addCommand( new Command( "Exit" ) );
        menuForm.setTransitionOutAnimator( CommonTransitions.createSlide( CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, true,
            200 ) );
        menuForm.addCommandListener( this );
    }
    return menuForm;
}

 public List getMenuList()
{
    String[] menuItems = { "Find Person", "Person Registration", "Message", "Setting" };
    if ( menuList == null )
    {
        menuList = new List( menuItems );
        menuList.setListCellRenderer( new DefaultListCellRenderer( false ) );
        menuList.setSmoothScrolling( true );
        menuList.setFixedSelection( List.FIXED_NONE );
        menuList.addActionListener( this );
    }
    return menuList;
}
```

I only can select 4 options of list, and I CAN'T scroll down to see the bottom of screen. Do I miss something here, please help me...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `menuForm` to scrollable false and let the list's scrollability take over. You have nested scrollables one in another and that produces a bad user experience.

Comment: thank Shai Almog, I reset following your guide, but still I can't scroll down to the bottom...

Comment: We made some fixes here in Codename One, I'm not sure how to help you with this on LWUIT though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do this:

```
menuList.setScroable(true);
```